# Python on Win 7 64bits error MS Access

Tags: python, ms-access, ms-office, anaconda

I have a serious problem, I don't now how to solve it.

I have a Win 7 64bit laptop, with MS Office 2007 installed (32 bits).

I installed Anaconda 64bits, BUT I am trying to connect to a MS Access MDB file with the ACE drives and I got an error that there is no driver installed.

Due to MS Office 2007, I was forced to install ACE drivers 32 bits.

Any help?
The same code runs perfect under Win XP, with exactly the same installed: Anaconda, ACE drivers and MS Office 2007.

It can be a problem mixin 32bits and 64 bits?

Comment: Does Anaconda have a 32 bit version you can try?  Everything else is 32 bits.  There is some precedent for this problem in other software: note that [Altova requires the 64 bit ACE driver](http://www.altova.com/Access-Database-OLEDB-32bit-64bit.html) for their software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it!

Yes, the problem was mixing 32 and 64 bits.

I solved the problem installing the Microsoft ACE Drivers 64bits on a MS-DOS console, writting:
**AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive**

And everything works!

Comment: Note for future readers: When a machine already has a copy of the Access Database Engine (ACE) driver installed, using the `/passive` switch to force an install of a second copy for the "other bitness" (e.g., to install the 64-bit version when the 32-bit version is already present) can break things, so proceed with caution. Whenever possible it is much preferred to only have one flavour of the Access Database Engine (i.e., 64-bit OR 32-bit) installed on a given machine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will have a problem mixing 32 and 64 bit like this.  The best thing to do is to download the 32-bit Windows Anaconda installer:

http://continuum.io/downloads